# iOS: Pro/Lite versions with pre-compilation in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, version, pre-compilation

I have a project whose a pro application target. I want to make a Lite version but not to make another project and copy-paste the files from the full project. Is there any pre-compilation way in Xcode to make two build settings and compiled code for the Pro and Lite versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can duplicate your current application target, and add in some preprocessor macros.  Say LITE for the lite version, then in your code do something similar to:

```
#ifdef LITE
//Lite
#else
//Pro
#endif
```